# Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms class not showing all software

Tags: reporting-services, wmi, sccm

I am having an issue reporting on Adobe Acrobat installations. I can view that Acrobat is installed under the registry location: HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\

However, I do not see it under the WMI class Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms or Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms64 on the local machine (possibly all machines at this point). The 64 bit class is actually showing the same software as the regular class (Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms). I installed Acrobat on my test machine, ran all policy retrieval requests on the machine for SCCM and Acrobat is not showing in the Add_Remove_Programs table for this machine. I am assuming it may have something to do with it not showing up in WMI. Does something need to be adjusted? Acrobat is showing on various machines across the Enterprise, but it is now reporting Acrobat is installed on various machines that it has been uninstalled on which is why I am performing testing. Any ideas?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't see the link with the `reporting-services` tag, is that because you need to open a SSRS report saved as PDF with acrobat?